how do you seperate the cells of the display:table-cell:
i have been coding a website manually but somehow i cant seperate the <div class = "content home-section"> </div> tag. Anyone who knows how to do so?
i tried seperating the tag before by using:
.content.homes-section{ margin-padding:30px; }
so if anyone has any suggestion please help.
